# JavaScript from ajax modified file doesn't work in main page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problems with a form and ajax behavior when I populate my dynamic div using JavaScript.

I have a drop box  which contains different time periods and it triggers JavaScript function which modifies the container div based on provided value.

The problem is that the POST behavior of the form and all JavaScript elements doesn't work in the main file.

Here is the code. I simplified it to emphasize the problem.
this is the drop Box:

```
//jQuery for datePicker comes here

<select id="QSelector" method="post" onchange="populateDiv(this.value)">
   <option value="0">All Values</option>
   <option value="1">Sets for 1</option>
   <option value="2">Sets for 2</option>
   <option value="3">Sets for 3</option>
   <option value="4">Sets for 4</option>
</select>

<div id="OUtputDiv" ></div>
```

here is the javascript function:

```
          function populateDiv(id){
          var xmlhttp;
          if(window.XMLHttpRequest){//safari, chrome, opera, ffox
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          else{//IE
             xmlhttp=ActiveXObject("Microft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             document.getElementById("OUtputDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET", "../scripts/supportFile.php?ID=" + id, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

And here is the content of the support file. don't mind the `id` variable it does some logic (ant it works), but I removed it because it's irrelevant to a given problem.

```
  <?php

     $Id= $_GET['ID'];
      echo "<script> alert('it works'); </script>";
      echo "<form name='AddForm' class='AddForm' method='post' >";
      echo "<span > Date: &nbsp; </span> <input type='textbox' id='datepicker' name='datepicker' > &nbsp;";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='SubBtn' value='Save' >";
      echo "</form>";

      if(isset($_POST['SubBtn']))
      {
          echo $_POST["datepicker"];
      }
   ?>
```

Nether JavaScript or JQuery  does not work from the main file. And form does not post anything if I press the save button.
Can anyone suggest how can I make it responsive in the main file where I call ajax function from?

Comment: anybody ? any ideas?

Comment: can you post the code for the populateDiv function

Comment: Actually the seond line of code is the `populateDiv` function

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using IE5/6 support, use jQuery instead:

The problem is that you put all code in the same page, it will not work in that way, you need to make 2 files, 1 for post 1 for result

Good:

test_post.php

```
<?php
      $Id = $_POST['id'];
      if(!empty($Id)){

          $result = "
                        <script> alert('it works'); </script>
                        <form name='AddForm' class='AddForm' method='post' >
                        <span > Date: &nbsp; </span> <input type='textbox' id='datepicker' name='datepicker' > &nbsp;
                        <input type='submit' name='SubBtn' value='Save' >
                        </form>
                    ";

          echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'result' => $result));
      }
?>
```

test.php

```
<select id="QSelector">
   <option value="0">All Values</option>
   <option value="1">Sets for 1</option>
   <option value="2">Sets for 2</option>
   <option value="3">Sets for 3</option>
   <option value="4">Sets for 4</option>
</select>

<div id="OUtputDiv" ></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on( "change", '#QSelector',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"<?php echo './test_post.php'; ?>",    
                    data: {id: id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.status == 'success'){
                            $('#OUtputDiv').html(data.result);
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If the IE is 6+ will work, read more about here: [link](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Comment: it is complaining about  `Undefined index: id on line 6`

Comment: I've never used jquery before. do I have to install something for it to work?

Comment: is there a Javascript alternative for the script you've suggested?

Comment: I'm not comfortable with Jquery at all. I mean is it ok if I just remove the IE suport form there.?

Comment: do we really have to include `"<?php echo './scripts/supportFile.php'; ?>",    ` in jQuerry function? besides the AllGood box does not pop up. so i assume the funtion does not work

Comment: I updated the Answer, you need to put your entire url, test in with console open in Firefox or Chrome and see if the url is right, if not, fix it and should work !

Comment: still the same problem. id is unudentified.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the JQurery?

Comment: I was just wondering why all the functionalities of JavaScript and post didn't work when I use the old-fashioned ajax? what exactly went wrong. I can't figure it our.

Comment: Let me know if now it works, you need to create 2 files

Comment: It's working now. But the datapicker is not responsible still

Comment: use it in the main file

Comment: ` $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });`

Comment: but it is not responsive still

Comment: and where shall I put the this in test_post file?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['SubBtn']))
      {
     echo $_POST["datepicker3"];
      }

Comment: I can not include it into result variable. can I?

Comment: JQuery is generally resulting to the same problem. Just a different approach to achieve them. I still can't understand why can't we use ajax instead?